# Is there RefEdit control equivalent in Libre Calc?

Tags: dialog, controls, libreoffice, opendocument, libreoffice-basic

Does anyone know what is Libre Calc’s equivalent for Excel’s RefEdit control? All other Excel UserForm controls seem to have corresponding controls for Libre Dialog forms. If there isn’t one, is it possible to tweak some other control (like Combo Box) into behaving like reference input box?

For those who don’t know RefEdit, it is the control that lets the user specify range address. More detailed explanation is e.g. in [How to code a .NET RefEdit Control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gabhan_berry/archive/2008/06/12/net-refedit-control.aspx) on Gabhan Berry’s Excel Programming blog or in [KB213776](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/213776).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such a possibility - you must use [XRangeSelectionListener](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Range_Selection)

By setting different [RangeSelectionArguments](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/RangeSelectionArguments.html) you will get different picker behavior.

[image: RefEdit_Demo.gif]

An example of a macro that is shown in this animation is here [RefEdit_Demo.ods](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iugw7h8myas1udk/RefEdit_Demo.ods?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you @JohnSUN. I'll update this tread once I test this solution but it seems to be what I needed.